# How would I, as a lone driver, operate a parking barrier when driving abroad on a different side of the road?

Tags: driving

If I were to take my car abroad to a country where they drive on the other side of the road, how would I operate parking barriers/toll booths etc. when I am sat on the other side of the car?

I'm thinking it would be almost impossible to try and reach through the car, but I'm not sure it would be possible to get out the car walk around and get back in either!

Comment: You might well find that [you had enough time to get out and pay](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/73159/12065).

Comment: Reverse through ;D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have seen three options in action.

1. First option, the reach across the car, and open window.
   If the car is not too big and the driver is good in positioning the car as near to barrier control as possible, it works.
2. Second option, reach across the car with an arm extender, that can be a [reach extender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reach_extender) if you have to hand over a card or a soup ladle if you need to hand coins into a wide container or someones hand. Turn the ladle and you have a point to push buttons.
3. *Warning, this can be illegal on main roads and can be dangerous depending on the kind of traffic.*
   Third option, get out of car, walk around, do what you need to do, walk around again, get in car and drive off.
   Most places should allow you enough time to do that but in some cases you may have to walk back and push the 'help' button to have them open the barrier again.
   If you plan to use this method and you find the time at the barriers is restricted, stop the car as far forward as acceptable, walk back quickly and drive forward/through the barrier before doing your safety belt, if at all possible.
   (Do the belt as soon as you are through the barrier.)
   [This question shows that most barriers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/73159/how-to-best-get-through-a-motorway-toll-booth-safely-between-paying-and-the-barr) seem to have enough time for you not to need to worry about being quick.

The easiest method it to have a passenger in the front seat to do the work for you. Which is ruled out by your question.

Comment: I'll leave this as a comment as I can't fine the right law article right now and I don't want to call my customers on Saturday to ask for it, but about point 3 be careful on suggesting something like that: not only it's extremely dangerous, but in EU on toll roads it could make you win some fines.

Comment: The question is about a parking barrier, so not a toll both on a main road. I do not know the legal side but I have seen it happen and I have read in the linked question that it is often done. I do not drive, I have been the passenger having to pay in a 'wrong side of the road' car quite a few times.

Comment: Well, the question says "toll booths etc.", so I thought it could be about toll roads, too. I've seen it happens a lot, too, along with lot of other things (I've been the project manager for software of control rooms of a few big highways in Italy for 7 years), and yes it's often done and usually don't get fined...unless the occasional time when things screw up, you end up in the hospital and then you get it topped with a nice bunch of fines. That's not a wise thing...